# How to set the return value for an IEnumerable class using NSubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I have this domain:

```
public class ADomainClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyClass : IEnumerable<ADomainClass>
{
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public IEnumerator<ADomainClass> GetEnumerator()
    {
        IList<ADomainClass> list = new List<ADomainClass>();
        //list = GetData...();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

and want to build the following test:

```
[Test]
public void TestSample()
{
    //Arrange
    IMyClass myclass = Substitute.For<IMyClass>();
    IList<ADomainClass> testdata = new List<ADomainClass>()
    {
        new ADomainClass(){ Id = 1, },
        new ADomainClass(){ Id = 2, },
        new ADomainClass(){ Id = 3, },
        new ADomainClass(){ Id = 4, },
    };
    int count = 0;

    myclass.ReturnsForAnyArgs(testdata); //How to set the "return" value?

    //Act
    foreach (ADomainClass item in myclass)
    {
        count++;
    }

    //Assert
    count.Should().Be(testdata.Count);
}
```

Setting the return value for a method is easy and would look like this:

```
myclass.GetData().Returns(data);
```

I can't remember how to set the return value when it is an enumerable class. I have solved this once before, but can't remember where I have used it.

Comment: Why? What has NHibernate to do with NSubstitute??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to tell your substitute to return the enumerator from you test data:

```
myclass.GetEnumerator().Returns(testdata.GetEnumerator());
```

Comment: This will not work as expected. You need to use a lambda (see @TvdH answer) to return a new enumerator each time. Else the enumerator will not be reset between multiple calls.

Answer (score 6):

My problem was that NSubstitute stores the state of the enum, so if you use the Enumerator twice in the system under test, it will continue with the second element at the second time. I am using something like the code below as a workaround (using a lambda instead of returning the Enumerator, lines 1 + 2 are for demonstration only). I have only tested this with some Linq and foreach.

```
var bar = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
var foo = Substitute.For<ICollection<string>>();
foo.GetEnumerator().Returns((ci) => { return bar.GetEnumerator(); });
```

Comment: Create a new question if you need help, please

Comment: This is an answer to the original question (on how to substitute an IEnumerable). I am not asking a question.

Comment: A slightly more compact expression: `sub.GetEnumerator().Returns(_ => GetEnumerator());`. The unused parameter is needed here.